# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present in request

Tags: java, angular, api, http, cors

I have read a lot of topic about this, and it still doesn't work, i'm loosing my mind.

I have an Angular6 App, with a Spring Api and i keep having this error when i call it :

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And yet i feel i did everything :

Here is my call to the api in Angular App:

```
getGamesFromServer() {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    })
  };

  this.httpClient
    .get<any[]>('http://localhost:8080/api/rest/v1/game/progress', httpOptions)
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.games = response;
        console.log(this.games);
        this.emitGameSubject();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Erreur ! : ' + error);
      }
    );
}
```

Here is the java method called :

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/progress")
@ResponseBody
public Response findAllAndProgress() {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
            .entity(gameService.findAllAndProgress())
            .header(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*")
            .build();
}
```

I have also started chrome with --disable-web-security option activated, and i also downloaded a chrome extension to allow CORS request but it was no use

Comment: Where is your angular app running from, port 4200?

Comment: Yes, angular app port 4200 and java api 8080

Comment: You don't need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the Angular front-end btw, it's just the API that needs to answer with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's because the Angular app is running in dev mode and is being served from a different port than the Spring webapp.  You can either solve this with a `proxy.conf.json` file that you specify to the app startup (`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`) or as a quick and dirty (but less production ready) solution you can add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` to your Spring controllers.

The reason that the following code doesn't work:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/progress")
@ResponseBody
public Response findAllAndProgress() {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
        .entity(gameService.findAllAndProgress())
        .header(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*")
        .build();
}
```

is because that method never actually gets executed to add the header.  Cross-origin requests initiate a preflight request (HTTP OPTION) before issuing the actual request (HTTP GET in your case).  It is that preflight request that is failing.  This is why adding the annotation to the controller will address the issue.

Comment: Ok i understand. I tried to add the annotation but when i add spring-web to my pom it doesn't work. I think i have dependencies with uncompatible version with spring-web

Answer (score 0):

Create proxy.conf.json file in root directory with next content:

```
{ 
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

And in package.json file you must change start script from `ng serve` to `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

More details about proxy-config: [Link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: Did not work... root directory is src or the real root ?

Comment: I think you need to add `"changeOrigin": true` pair after `target` and `secure`

Answer (score 0):

On java add following this line on your api

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

You can also proxy your request from Angular side. Angular provide you inbuilt server that can proxy request. Following following steps:

1. Add proxy.config.json file on root directory of your project.
2. Add following code in proxy.config.json file

   {
       "/api/": {
         "target": {
           "host": "localhost",
           "protocol": "http:",
           "port": 8080
         },
         "secure": false,
         "changeOrigin": true,
         "logLevel": "debug"
       }
     }
3. In package.json find start under scripts and replace with following:

   ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
4. Edit your angular code with following code:

   this.httpClient
   .get('/api/rest/v1/game/progress', httpOptions)
   .subscribe(
     (response) => {
       console.log(response);
       this.games = response;
       console.log(this.games);
       this.emitGameSubject();
     },
     (error) => {
       console.log('Erreur ! : ' + error);
     }
   );